# jQuery selector to select all types of textboxes

Tags: jquery

Is there an easy way to select all types of textboxes?

ie. `<input type=` text or email or url or number `/>`

I don't mind password or textarea.

eg. I have this code that selects all text inputs having a custom attribute ('special'), can it be shortened?

```
$("input[type='text'][special],input[type='email'][special],input[type='url'][special],input[type='password'][special]")
```

Comment: I surely don't get it, but if you can apply a special attribute, why not a class ?

Comment: just to make it shorter, eg. <input DefaultText='Your email' /> rather than <input class='hasDefaultText' DefaultText='Your email' />

Answer (score 5):

Does the [:input selector](http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/) cover the cases you're interested in?

```
$(":input[special]")
```

**Docs:**

> The `:input selector` basically selects all form controls.
>
> **Additional Notes:**
> Because `:input` is a jQuery extension and not part of the CSS specification, queries using `:input` cannot take advantage of the performance boost provided by the native DOM querySelectorAll() method. To achieve the best performance when using `:input` to select elements, first select the elements using a pure CSS selector, then use [`.filter(":input")`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/).

```
$("[special]").filter(":input");
```

Comment: Why not just $("input[special]")? But that will select checkbox hidden etc too

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
$(':input[special]')
```

Although that will also grab checkboxes etc.

http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/

Answer (score 0):

You can be using `$(":input[special]")` or `$("[special]").filter(":input")`;

But i think this is faster:

```
$("input").filter(function() {
    return this.type !== "hidden" && this.getAttribute("special");
});
```

Or without `radio` and `checkbox`'es

```
$("input").filter(function() {
    return this.type !== "hidden" && this.type !== "radio" && this.type !== "checkbox" && this.getAttribute("special");
});
```

**See docs for [`:input`](http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/)**

> The `:input selector` basically selects all form controls.
>
> **Additional Notes:**
> Because `:input` is a jQuery extension and not part of the CSS specification, queries using `:input` cannot take advantage of the performance boost provided by the native DOM querySelectorAll() method. To achieve the best performance when using `:input` to select elements, first select the elements using a pure CSS selector, then use [`.filter(":input")`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/).